Exponential distrubution problem
I am working on a problem involving the probability of headlights in a car failing. The failure rate is given by the exponential distribution function $f(x) = 0.2e^{-0.2x}$, where x is the time in years.
I need to calculate the probability that the headlights do not fail within the time span between 2 years and 3 years.
My understanding is as follows:

The integral of $f(x)$ from 2 to 3 years gives the probability that the headlights fail between 2 and 3 years.
Therefore, to find the probability that the headlights do not fail between 2 and 3 years, I need to subtract this value from 1.

Mathematically, I expressed it as:
$ P(\text{no failure between 2 and 3 years}) = 1 - \int_{2}^{3} 0.2e^{-0.2x} dx $
However, my book suggests that the probability of the headlights not failing between 2 and 3 years is just the value of the integral from 2 to 3 of the function. What I mean is that the answer the book gave was approximately 12%.
This seems contradictory to me both intuitively and calculation based. Could anyone help clarify this?
Thank you!

$\int\limits_{2}^{3} 0.2e^{-0.2x} dx =e^{-0.4}-e^{-0.6} \approx 0.1215$ is the initial probability of failing in that interval.

Hi @Henry! I understand that the integral of the function between 2 and 3 equals around 12%. However, the desired outcome was supposed to be the probability of not destroying/failing in that interval. Would that not equal to approximately 88%, indicating that the answer the book provided may be wrong?

I would agree with you. $0.1215$ is approximately the initial probability of failing in that interval.
